# 3.3V TTL is dropping to 2v when connected to pin

Tags: ttl

3.3V TTL is dropping to 2v when connected to pin. can i use a current limiting resistor in series to maintain 3.3v. Need suggestions.

Comment: Pin of what? Please post a schematic. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: post a schematic

Comment: If it's dropping from 3.3V down to 2V its because the 3.3V source can't drive HI hard enough for the pin it's connected to. As to WHY this is happening, we need a schematic, and to know what the driver, sink and other loads are on the line.

Comment: 74LS or  what? or  2V is a valid TTL "1" So what?

Answer (score 1):

3.3V LVTTL logic only guarantees a high of 2.4V (Voh) at its rated current. What is the load? If it’s too much for your device you may need to add a buffer. If it needs to be a ‘true’ 3.3V, then it needs to be a FET buffer which can swing all the way to the positive rail.